# sequelize includes not returning data

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get data mapped with empid from 2 tables viz-skillsrepo and certifications and render it to frontend,I am getting all data from certifications table,but i need data only of the empid which i send in request

tried using includes method

```
app.get('/updateprofile/:id', function (req, res) {
  db.skillsrepo.find({
    where: { employeeId: req.params.id },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.certifications
      },
      {
        model: db.attachments
      },
      {
        model: db.project
      }
    ]
  }).then(result => {
    if (result != null) {
      res.render('updateprofile', {
        user: result,
        eid: req.params.id,

      });
      console.log("**********", result)
    }
  })
});
```

This is the Schema:

```
var skillsrepo = exports.skillsrepo = connection.define('skillsrepo', {
  firstname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  lastname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  highQual: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  fivekeystrenghts: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  domain: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  technicalskills: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  typesoftesting: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(23)
  },
  employeeId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
    references: {
      model: 'employeemastertablee',
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
});

skillsrepo.hasMany(certifications, {
  foreignKey: "employeeId"
});

certifications.belongsTo(skillsrepo, {
  foreignKey: "employeeId"
});
```

Comment: Please Post your `skillsrepo` model schema in the question.

Comment: var skillsrepo = exports.skillsrepo = connection.define('skillsrepo',{
 firstname:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(23) } ,
 lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(23) },
 highQual : {
 type: Sequelize.STRING(23)},
 fivekeystrenghts: {
 type: Sequelize.TEXT },
 domain: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(23) },  
 technicalskills: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(23) },  
 typesoftesting: {
 type: Sequelize.STRING(23)},
 employeeId:{
 type:Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
 references: {
 model: 'employeemastertablee',
 key: 'id' 
}}}

Comment: skillsrepo.hasMany(certifications, { foreignKey: "employeeId" });
certifications.belongsTo(skillsrepo,{ foreignKey: "employeeId" });